# Is it possible to access "Data Science" on Stack Exchange using an API?

Tags: education, chatbot, question-answering, api

I am a programmer with C and Python knowledge. I am trying to "educate" or train my Chatbot with name "Stella" in "Science and Technology History" and related areas, helped by ChatGPT 3.5.
I am already using contents provided by Wikipedia, but some a question and answer format about specific topics could be of great help.

Comment: Hi @user545577, welcome to the site. Have you tried Googling "stackexchange API"?